# match 3 patterns (2 static, one variable) and change the variable one

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Cant for the life of me figure this one out, thought i had it sorted, but no

I have an XML file that has entries like the following

```
<compat-change description="Flag {@link android.content.Context#BIND_INCLUDE_CAPABILITIES} is used to pass while-in-use capabilities from client process to bound service. In targetSdkVersion R and above, if client is a TOP activity, when this flag is present, bound service gets all while-in-use capabilities; when this flag is not present, bound service gets no while-in-use capability from client." enableAfterTargetSdk="29" id="136274596" name="PROCESS_CAPABILITY_CHANGE_ID"/>
```

I need to match the id and name (always static values and in same order in line) but change the Sdk value (which is variable)

```
Sdk="29" id="136274596" name="PROCESS_CAPABILITY"
```

I did try

```
sed -i '/Sdk=\"[0-9]\+\".*id="143937733".*name="PROCESS_CAPABILITY"/ {s/Sdk=\"[0-9]\+\"/Sdk=\"0\"/1;}'
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better served by a proper XML tool such as `xmlstarlet`, something like

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '
  //compat-change[@id="136274596"][starts-with(@name,"PROCESS_CAPABILITY")]/@enableAfterTargetSdk
' -v 0 file.xml
```

ex.

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//compat-change[@id="136274596"][starts-with(@name,"PROCESS_CAPABILITY")]/@enableAfterTargetSdk' -v 0 file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<compat-change description="Flag {@link android.content.Context#BIND_INCLUDE_CAPABILITIES} is used to pass while-in-use capabilities from client process to bound service. In targetSdkVersion R and above, if client is a TOP activity, when this flag is present, bound service gets all while-in-use capabilities; when this flag is not present, bound service gets no while-in-use capability from client." enableAfterTargetSdk="0" id="136274596" name="PROCESS_CAPABILITY_CHANGE_ID"/>
```

See [How to filter on multiple attributes in XMLStarlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474027/4440445)

Comment: thanks but thats not going to work for me, i was looking for a solution purely using existing inbuilt commands, thanks

Comment: update: i found, beyond all hope, a binary for android, so it might work :)

Comment: update #2: works perfectly and i get why its a saner choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(Sdk=")[^"]*(" id="136274596" name="PROCESS_CAPABILITY)/\10\2/' input_file
<compat-change description="Flag {@link android.content.Context#BIND_INCLUDE_CAPABILITIES} is used to pass while-in-use capabilities from client process to bound service. In targetSdkVersion R and above, if client is a TOP activity, when this flag is present, bound service gets all while-in-use capabilities; when this flag is not present, bound service gets no while-in-use capability from client." enableAfterTargetSdk="0" id="136274596" name="PROCESS_CAPABILITY_CHANGE_ID"/>
```

Comment: cheers, this works also and was closer to what i was initially looking for!

the grouping makes more sense than my own hobbled attempts :)